# WCF Web service isn't reading web.Config correctly...Why?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, .net-4.0, web-config

I am trying to make a web service that helps us interact with data in a third-party database.  The web service works, but it seems it isn't taking the configuration I tell it to in the `web.config` file.

```
<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="ContactService">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="restEnabled" binding="webHttpBinding"
      name="Contacts" contract="IContacts" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restEnabled">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

I would assume with this config that I would get a help page, JSON out, and it should never wrap the response from the server.  None of this occurs...

When I ran a trace on the service I see a warning of `Configuration evaluation context not found`.  I read the other posts on SO about this but I don't think they apply to me since my configuration is in the `web.config` file.  Does anyone have any idea's what could be causing this and how to correct it?

I can get it to work by adding parameters to the `WebGet`/`WebInvoke` attributes, but I don't want to have a ton of repeated code at the top of all my methods.

EDIT:  I am using the Factory directive in the .svc file.  Even then I did add the FQN of the service and contract and it made no difference.

Comment: The `<service name="ContactService">` must **exactly match** your service implementation's class name **and its namespace** - does it? Same goes for the `contract=` attribute on `<endpoint>` - it must exactly match the service contract interface including namespace(s).

Comment: @marc_s You are correct sir...Hope I'm not the only one that stares at the the screen saying, "WTF" and missing something so obvious...